# How to completely remove quick access from file explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-10-quick-access

I want to completely remove quick access from the file explorer.

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1409261) removes it from the left panel but when I right-click folders it still gives me the option to add them to the quick access.

If I add them and show the quick access again they're there. How can I remove that option too?

Comment: Untested, but I imagine that deleting `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\pintohome` might do the trick

Comment: @KeithMiller First I only renamed it in case it didn't worked and I wanted to restore it but it didn't so I tried deleting and it did worked. Thanks ^^